# How to include same sources in 2 different Makefiles?

Tags: c++, makefile, include, gnu-make

I have the following project structure:

```
Program
...Common
...Net
...Msg
...Tool
   ...Common
      ... tool.h
      ... tool.cpp
   ...Makefile (2)
...Common.inc
...Makefile (1)
```

So, i'd like to build tool.h and tool.cpp (Tool) from the sources in Msg, Net and Common.
I added all needed pathes in INCLUDE variable. But, when it comes to include directives in .cpp files i can't figure out how to properly include these files 1 level up from "Tool" folder.

I tried this:
#include "../msg/file.h"
But it doesn't work.

Comment: You will have to be more clear about what you want to do.  Also, "it doesn't work" is not a problem we can help with.  Please cut and paste (with code block formatting) the actual commands you ran and the errors you got, and describe more clearly what programs or libraries you want to create and what object files should go into them, and from which sources, and what needs to be included by what.

Comment: Are you sure you need multiple Makefiles at all? A single Makefile is easier to get started with. Have the top-level Makefile add `-I.` to your `CXXFLAGS` and use full relative paths in your Makefile. Then you can just `#include "Msg/file.h"` from anywhere in your project and it will work.

Comment: After that you can refine your Makefile to put build- and intermediate files in a separate directory, enable out-of-tree builds, properly track dependencies based on the compiler's `-MMF` output, etc. Or you can just use a higher-level build system such as CMake and get all of that for free :)

Comment: I fully endorse @Botje's comment and answer.  With that said, however, most C++ compilers do understand relative paths in `#include` directives, including with parent-directory steps such as `#include "../msg/file.h"`.  But that particular path is not correct for referencing `Program/Msg/file.h` from file `Program/Tool/Common/tool.cpp`.  To use that approach in that file, you would want `#include "../../Msg/file.h"`.  Note both the capitalization and the number of upward steps in the path.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in one top-level Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS += -O2 -I.
COMMON_SOURCES = common/foo.cpp common/bar.cpp
NET_SOURCES = net/baz.cpp net/quux.cpp
MSG_SOURCES = msg/apple.cpp

ALL_SOURCES = $(COMMON_SOURCES) $(NET_SOURCES) $(MSG_SOURCES)

all: Tool/Tool

Tool/Tool: Tool/Common/Tool.o $(ALL_SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
  $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

That is sufficient for `make` (or `make all` or `make Tool/Tool`) to compile all sources and put them together, where you can use include paths relative to the root of your project such as `#include "Msg/file.h"`.